# Docker error durante la conexión

Tags: docker

Estoy intentando correr:

```
docker run -dp 80:80 docker/getting-started
```

Intente corriendo el comando como administrador sin éxito, haciendo checking "Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS" en setting y ejecutando el demonio manualmente con ./DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon, docker ps muestra lo siguiente:

```
docker ps
error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.40/containers/json: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
PS C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker> Docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.8
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.17
 Git commit:        afacb8b
 Built:             Wed Mar 11 01:23:10 2020
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false
error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.40/version: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
```

por qué podría suceder, cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

Comment: ¿Ya probaste todo lo que dice aquí https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1825?

Comment: Sí probé esas soluciones

Comment: Checa el estado de Hyper-V, deshabilita/desinstala todo lo relacional y vuelve a activarlo/instalarlo. Y checa en tu Docker Desktop si te marca algún aviso o algo más...realmente está muy raro, reinstala también el mismo Docker desde el desktop a ver si te ayudara.